# Should lodash's cloneDeep method also clone the data type alone with the data

Tags: typescript, lodash, typedoc

I am using cloneDeep to clone the data of an Object into another variable.
The data type of source data is a custom interface, let's say, IVehicle.

Now, after the cloning is done the destination variable type is 'any'

Here is the code:

```
const vehicleInfo = cloneDeep(someCar);
```

someCar is of type IVehicle but resulting vehicleInfo is of type 'any'.

Parallely i was trying to generate documentation for my angular project using typedoc.

Once I use typedoc in the project, the vehicleInfo datatype is not 'any' but IVehicle.

can some one explain this phenomenon?

Comment: I tried this out quickly and couldn't reproduce. Typescript is inferring the return type of `cloneDeep` as `typeof THE_PARAMETER`, not `any`

Comment: @Chic could you post your code that you tried. The code line above is being resulting into any. I am using VSCode. If I hover over the vehicleInfo I see the type as 'any' if I do not have typedoc installed in the package.